# How can you put Admob ID in app when you only get ID after you publish the app

Tags: admob

I know this isn't strictly a programming question and I apologise for that in advance.

There seems to be a "chicken and egg" situation with Admob ads. How is it possible to put the  publisher ID in the app when you don't get the ID until after you have published it? I know I must be looking at it all wrong, but I can't get my head round it, and I can't find anything on the web, or on Google or Admob's sites. Can anyone please help?

Answer (score 4):

When you create an AdMob site/app, you don't have to specify your Play store package url.  You can leave that blank and just go back and fill it in later when you publish your app.

Hence, you can get an AdMob ID before you publish an app.

Comment: Thanks mate you are absolutely right - wish they could make that a bit clearer in the Admob website.