# Is there a way to link an Android app to Admob when it is only published in alpha?

Tags: android, google-play, admob

I have an android app that is in alpha and being tested by a group of people. I have not yet published it publicly. The app has Admob integrated and I have set up an Admob and gotten an id for the app and so on.

The problem is that there seems to impossible to link the app in admob. The dialog that shows up when clicking "Link your app" has a search field, but the app is not searchable since it is only published in alpha, though it is available on google play for the members of the alpha test group.

[Other questions on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10639840/how-can-you-put-admob-id-in-app-when-you-only-get-id-after-you-publish-the-app) do not seem to [address this particular problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25097694/publishing-an-alpha-vsersion-of-my-android-app).

So the question is, is it even possible to link an android app that is currently only published in alpha to Admob? If it is, how is that done?

Comment: if you read the AdMob SDK guide it shows how to use Test Ads;; How do I get test ads?
The ad unit that we provide in this guide and the samples returns test ads. You can also request test ads by using AdRequest.Builder.addTestDevice.

Comment: Yep, I have tried test ads during development. No I was trying to set up the complete chain with the linked app in Admob, which seems to not be possible.

Comment: Sorry, it seems strange AdMob dont offer this test service. I know TapJoy does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would write a comment instead of an answer, but currently I'm not yet able to do so.

I had the same scenario a couple of days ago => a new app in alpha status with AdMob ads.

After I uploaded the Alpha APK and waited a few hours the app was available to be linked with the AdMob entry.

Did you wait a bit until you checked whether it is available?
Do you have a different Google Account for AdMob and is this one part of the Alpha Test Group?

These are the two things i can think of why it didn't (or did not yet) appear.

Bottom line: for me it worked; so it is definitely possible.

Comment: This was it. I was impatient :) I used the bundle ID in the search box and it turned up.